Debugger does not seem to be working in VS Code
I am on Windows 11 and not even a single cpp debugger is working properly. I tried like 3-4 (all possible on Windows maybe) and all have issues.
Many times its this fault: when I start debugging, the code gets stuck at some unknown line (code is giving output when run normally) and all the step over, step in, step out options are greyed and unusable. I am unable to give any input in integrated terminal (I want to use integrated terminal). The only option left is to play the code (press pause twice and then play twice then give the input) which just leads to output (why I need a debugger then?).
Further the terminal was taking input and when I am able to give, all that what I pressed when terminal was rejecting input, is typed in terminal. I have cmake (extension), gdb, strawberry, mingw, cpp debugging extension, etc.
Please help me I tried a lot. The clang via Visual Studio also did not work. Everything works fine in linux but not in Windows (I know, I have done everything separately for Windows, do not assume I used linux files to use on Windows). Further when I try to fix it and write test code, it works fine but for my codeforces codes it gets stuck and creates a mess.
not taking input but terminal is saving the typed things
all debugging features are greyed out
in the end just giving the output of code
Many times its like when there is fault the debugger stops working and I can not see any variable in side windows. When there is some problem in code , debugger just do not do anything.
Plus all the path variables, location of gdb, g++ all are fine. I even have two compilers. but nothing works.
Please please please help me
I tried configuring launch.json, task.json, cpp properties.json, all. Everything is fine. I tried lots of tasks ...
launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build"
    },

    {
      "name": "Debug with Input",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": false
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "miDebuggerArgs": "< ${fileDirname}/input.txt"
    },
    {
      "name": "C++ Debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build and run with input",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "e:/software_dev/CPP/CodeForces/23_jun_24",
      "program": "e:/software_dev/CPP/CodeForces/23_jun_24/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
  ]
}

tasks.json
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "run with input and output redirection",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd",
                "args": [
                    "/c",
                    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe < ${fileDirname}\\input.txt > ${fileDirname}\\output.txt"
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": "build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build"
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build"
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

